# how to open hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/

Tags: shell, hadoop, directory, mapreduce, hdfs

I tried to create a directory in hadoop by using command
     **hadoop fs -mkdir count**
so how to open  or see **hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/count**  on single node cluster?

Answer (score 2):

In order to see the folder and it's contents, you can do something like follows:

```
hadoop fs -ls count
```

And if you want to get the content to your local file system, then you can use `get`

```
hadoop fs -get count <output-path-in-your-local-filesystem>
```

For more detailed account on all command line options, read [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.1/hdfs_shell.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -lsr count
```

or

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/count
```